# Instagram API: Fetch Videos Only

Tags: instagram

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249010/instagram-video-search)

Is it possible to make a request to the API that will only return videos as opposed to a mix of videos and photos?

Right now every request I make I parse out the videos and display them. A lot of the time the response includes 20 objects, the majority of which are photos, and only leaves me with 1 or 2 videos if I'm lucky.

Is there anyway to get a response only composed of video objects?

Comment: Not currently, u have to manually parse

Answer (score 0):

In Instagram there is just one parameter called media to fetch the photos and videos.

After we have fetched all the videos and photos we can they sort only the videos from the bucket locally and save it.

This is the only option